# Running a dynamic amount of asynchronous tasks in bash

Tags: bash

I have a bash-script that should run a synchronize task `oil r cron:sync $id` on all IDs in a config file, as I'm quite new to bash, I was wondering about how to do it.

The thing is, syncs have to be done every 10 seconds, and it should not wait for a sync, thus I'm using `&` between the syncs

Currently I have this file:

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /var/www/script/

i="0";

function dsync {
        oil r cron:sync $1
}


while [ $i -lt 10 ]; do
        echo ">> Syncing IDs - loop $i"
        dsync 126776804 & dsync 108792704 & dsync 108291602

        sleep 10
        i=$[$i+1]
done
```

Now the question is, what if I have a file with on each line the IDs that have to be synced, how would I go by doing this ?

Comment: Please explain more about how syncing happens or how it should happen.

Comment: as you can see in the while loop, a sync is just the command `dsync ID`, any sync can take from 1ms to 5 seconds, and they should run simultaneously

Comment: You mean all three should run simultaneously but should end simultaneously as well every loop? Or at least before going to another loop, it should be made sure that all dsyncs are finished?

Comment: It does not matter if they're finished or not, the underlying script in `oil r cron:sync` handles that. i __just__ need them run without bash waiting for them.

Comment: Then why not place `dsync 108291602` to background as well? and also why do `sleep`? I'm sorry if don't follow quickly. I'm just new to the application.

Comment: The sleep is there to sync them again after 10 seconds.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57909/discussion-between-sander-and-konsolebox).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want is something like:

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /var/www/script/

i="0";

function dsync {
        oil r cron:sync $1
}


while [ $i -lt 10 ]; do
        echo ">> Syncing IDs - loop $i"

        for j in $(cat ids.txt); do
          dsync $j &
        done

        sleep 10
        i=$[$i+1]
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax when starting the tasks is wrong. To start them all in background you need to place them on separate lines:

```
dsync 126776804 &
dsync 108792704 &
dsync 108291602 &
```

You are further saying `it should not wait for a sync`. Having this, I assume that you don't care about the return status of the tasks, is this assumption correct?

Answer (score 1):

For variable count of parallel evocations of the `dsync` you can use the `xargs` in form:

```
xargs -n1 -I% -P0 oil r cron:sync % < filename_with_IDs
```

example with a pipe

```
seq 100010 100015 | xargs -n1 -I% -P0 echo oil r cron:sync %
```

produces

```
oil r cron:sync 100011
oil r cron:sync 100010
oil r cron:sync 100012
oil r cron:sync 100013
oil r cron:sync 100014
oil r cron:sync 100015
```

(ofc, you need remove the `echo`)

The `-P0` ensures than any number of arguments will be executed in parallel (forked into background)

from the man:

> -P max-procs
>
> Run up to max-procs processes at a time; the default is 1.  If max-procs is 0, xargs will  run  as  many
> processes  as  possible  at a time.  Use the -n option with -P; otherwise chances are that only one exec
> will be done.